# Realm db in lib + Realm db in app using the lib is conflicting with each other

Tags: android, database, sdk, realm

I have created an SDK which uses Realm db to store data. see code below how i have initialized my sdk db

```
  Realm.init(application);
  config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("sdk.db")
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
  Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

Similarly for App in the application class.

- First app db is created and initialized and the sdk method is called,which internally creates and initializes sdk.db.

But when i run the app i get following error

> io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Async transaction failed
>
> **Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: 'class com.models.db.FavouriteIdsModel' is not part of the schema for this Realm.**
>
> at io.realm.internal.RealmProxyMediator.getMissingProxyClassException(RealmProxyMediator.java:234)
>           at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.getSimpleClassNameImpl(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:82)
>           at io.realm.internal.RealmProxyMediator.getSimpleClassName(RealmProxyMediator.java:72)
>           at io.realm.RealmSchema.getTable(RealmSchema.java:177)
>           at io.realm.Realm.delete(Realm.java:1689)
>           at com.jiostb.jiogames.databaserealm.FavouriteMethod$4.execute(FavouriteMethod.java:79)
>           at io.realm.Realm$1.run(Realm.java:1601)
>           at io.realm.internal.async.BgPriorityRunnable.run(BgPriorityRunnable.java:34)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

and when i see db files, i am getting strange things

- sdk.db data is store in app.db and sdk.db also has the same data

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance that the SDK is overriding the default configuration, instead of using its own internal RealmConfiguration.

Also, if a library module wants to expose its schema for another module, you must use `@RealmModule` annotation with `library = true`, and specify that on the configuration.